# How to make a div scrollable vertical?

Tags: javascript, css

I used a package [ToastUI Grid](https://nhn.github.io/tui.grid/latest/tutorial-example03-custom-editor) in my project. Currently I'm having a problem with the package.
It seems it cannot vertical scroll within the grid. But when I move out my mouse cursor to the grid, the scrolling just works fine. (see [demo video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1grkH4K-NQWHsz7w2RUDPHu4z46zKmksD/view?usp=sharing))

I have tried posting an issue to their github project. But I received no response of it.
I just wondering if there is a way, we can forcefully make this as scrollable using Javascript or css.

---

This code looks like below,

```
const grid = new Grid({
    el: document.getElementById('grid2'),
    data: gridData,
    ... more code here
});
```

And if I inspect the element of the grid it looks like this,

```
<div id="grid2">
    <div data-grid-id="1" class="tui-grid-container tui-grid-show-lside-area" style="width: 100%;">
        ... more code here
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Updated:** I added here a [codepen](https://codepen.io/escbooster12/pen/bGjKEmj).

Comment: Please create a fiddle/ working example

Comment: The thing is that the plugin you use hijacks the `wheel` event and prevents the default action. This means that it will not propagate to the top and the browser will not act to it.

Comment: as @GabrielePetrioli said, the scroll disable is intentional for some reason, you could always remove that `wheel` event, but it will probably cause the table not to work properly

Comment: I have submitted a PR to the project that only prevents the default action if there is scroll available to happen inside the grid, otherwise it allows it to bubble up and be handled by the browser as it should.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli oh I saw your PR. Can you provide details as well on how to use it :)